# Python shell is restarted every time I do “run module” inside editor?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, ubuntu

I am using python 2 on Ubuntu and
when writing `import webbrowser 
webbrowser.open("fb.com")`
and run the module, the shell restarts and nothing happens. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by *run the module*.

If you just want to open fb.com, then try `webbrowser.open('http://fb.com')`. Give the `http://` so it doesn't try to open with `file://` or something.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without any code presented, but most likely you have not defined which browser it should use and/or you don't have one set as a default.

Try registering a controller for the browser you want:

```
import webbrowser 
ff_controller = webbrowser.get("firefox")
ff_controller.open("fb.com")
```

See additional available browser controllers [in the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register). If this isn't what's wrong post some code.